# PHP cUrl 0 content length, no errors

Tags: php, curl

I have this cUrl request that works sometimes, then stops working. I am echoing the header and any errors, http shows 200 ok and no errors, but content length is 0.

```
$userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
$cslbnum = "881126";
$target_url =      "https://www2.somewebsite.aspx?LicNum=" .   $cslbnum;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,  "https://www2.somesite.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$html = @mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
curl_close( $ch );

echo $html;
```

Any ideas what could cause this? I swear this morning I woke up it worked, got home from work, nothing. Tested the site directly, works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the last bit of your code - you're calling `curl_exec` twice.

```php
// ...
$html = curl_exec($ch);
if($html === false)
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
$html = @mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
curl_close( $ch );
echo $html;
```

Also, consider avoiding `@`.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt catch that, I have been fuddling with this for hours. Still showing content length 0 and not displaying the page though, very frustrating

Comment: @savagenoob Is your URL supposed to be `https://www2.somewebsite.com/default.aspx?LicNum=`?

Comment: No but I dont want to post on a forum... I can send to you, is there a way to pm on here? maybe a personal email?

Comment: @savagenoob I have a way of preventing spam, so please execute this script on a non-public server, it will give you my email address. **Code:** `<?php
$string = 'c2hhbm9xdWluKGRvdCkyKGF0KWxpc3BhbXZlKGRvdCljb20=';
$email = base64_decode($string);
$email = str_replace('(at)', '@', $email);
$email = str_replace('(dot)', '.', $email);
$email = str_replace('no', '', $email);
$email = str_replace('spam', '', $email);
echo $email;
?>`